# How to use testNG annotations in intellij IDEA 2017.1.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I am trying to use TestNG annotations and reports in my selenium project.But I am only getting junit libraries to be imported.

Below are my settings:

[image]

[image]

Hence it would really helpful, if someone could help me in resolving the issue.
Thanks,
Suthej

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a jar with TestNG in the classpath.
Find out more about Maven and/or Gradle.
With those tools you can easily add a dependency to your project.